# How to implement a custom Service Worker with Workbox in Nextjs

Tags: webpack, service-worker, next.js, vercel, workbox-webpack-plugin

I'm trying to properly implement a Service Worker using [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin) via [next-offline](https://github.com/hanford/next-offline). To create a custom service worker I'm using the *InjectManifest* class of the workbox-webpack-plugin. I'm having issues around setting up a dev environment for running the "now dev" command.

My current attempt is here: https://github.com/awb305/nextjs-service-worker-workbox.

Here are my issues:

1. **Failing to install**

When running "now dev" my SW will fail to install and log:

```
Uncaught (in promise) bad-precaching-response: The precaching request for 'http://localhost:3000/public/service-worker.js.map?__WB_REVISION__=a7274c8542abc1c5ddaad6ca132a250e' failed with an HTTP status of 404.
at PrecacheController._addURLToCache (http://localhost:3000/service-worker.js:956:13)
at async Promise.all (index 0)
at async PrecacheController.install (http://localhost:3000/service-worker.js:874:5)
```

unless I add the following redirects in my now.json file:

```
  {
    "src": "/public/(.*)",
    "status": 301,
    "headers": { "Location": "/" }
  },
  {
    "src": "/_next/static/development/pages/next/dist/pages/(.*)",
    "status": 301,
    "headers": { "Location": "/" }
  }
```

This solves the bad-precaching-reponse, however I haven't see this implemented elsewhere, so I'm not confident with this approach. ***What is the standard way to insure a correct SW install?***

2. **Webpack Warning**

When running "now dev" with my fix from my first issue I will get the following warning:

```
InjectManifest has been called multiple times, perhaps due to running webpack in --watch mode. The precache manifest generated after the first call may be inaccurate! Please see https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1790 for more information.
```

Currently my only fix is to toggle the **generateInDevMode** config in my next.config.js. I have to run "now dev" once with *generateInDevMode: true* if I want to install a new service worker. Then I have kill "now dev" and set *generateInDevMode: false* to prevent the previous warning from showing. Ideally, I'd rather not do this.

I tried setting my webpack config to:

```
webpackDevMiddleware(config) {
 // Fixes npm packages that depend on `fs` module
 config.node = {
  fs: "empty"
};
config.watch = false; 
return config;}
```

However this didn't take away the warning.

I'm having difficulty tracking down the bug. ***Is there anyway to surface more errors? Am I incorrectly setting the webpack watch config?***

Comment: Did you get an answer to this?

Comment: Unfortunately no ... I’m still toggling generateInDevMode when I want to create a new SW.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. and i decided to not use the next-offline and directly using `workbox`. if you use `workbox` directly you have move control on your service-worker and more coverage on your needs.

Comment: @younnes
1) Can you tell me where you declared the service worker? Inside public folder?

2) "TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:3000/') with script ('http://localhost:3000/service-worker.mjs'): ServiceWorker script evaluation failed"

How did you get over the above error?

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK i had used GenerateSW in next.config.js that creates service-worker.js and manifest.js in build folder _next.

Comment: Could you share your next.config.js in a fiddle maybe? Just curious.

Comment: Do you mean this?
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin#injectmanifest_plugin
Adding it on the webpack part of the next.config.js?